# HTTP caching headers: how should must-revalidate work?

Tags: proxy, http, cache

Using [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), I'm getting a response with the following header:

```
Cache-control: must-revalidate
```

Moreover, no 'Expires' header is being sent. Our local proxy, however, is caching these responses, so when an edit is made, pages need to be 'hard refreshed' to update. Is the proxy misbehaving? Other headers that *might* be relevant:

```
Connection          Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive          timeout=15, max=100
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP allows responses to be cached, even if they don't have explicit Expires or Cache-Control headers.

Specifically, they're allowed to calculate their own so-called heuristic freshness for responses with certain HTTP status codes (including `200 OK`). Usually, this is based upon the value of the `Last-Modified` header; e.g., if LM is 1 day ago when the response is first stored, a cache might figure that it's safe to assume it's fresh for 2 hours.

`must-revalidate` is an instruction that tells caches that once something becomes stale, it has to be checked on the origin server. If it isn't present, caches can (generally) use stale responses in unusual circumstances (e.g., if they lose contact with the origin server).

So, no, this cache doesn't look like it's misbehaving, although it sounds like it might be a bit aggressive in calculating heuristic freshness. If you don't want the cache to store the response at all, try `Cache-Control: no-store`, or (preferably) just set an explicit `max-age` to control how long it's considered fresh.

You might be interested in having a look at the IETF HTTPbis Working Group's current document that covers caching:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache

which hopefully makes this a bit clearer than RFC2616.

Also, http://redbot.org/ will check URLs and explain how caches handle specific response directives.

Comment: You say that "caches are allowed to calculate their own heuristic freshness". Is there a supporting RFC statement backing up this?

Comment: RFC2616, along with draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache, which will soon replace it (as far as caching goes).

Comment: Are you aware the timeframe when the draft is scheduled for release?

Comment: Soon. It's post-Working Group Last Call now, and should be in IETF Last Call by mid-September. With any luck it'll be an RFC by the end of the year.